# Seekbar full width makes thumb not in correct position

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I want to display seekbar match to whole width.I set padding as 0dp.But my thumb was not start and end in correct position[image]

```
    <SeekBar
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/bottomLayout" />
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @Ahamed ..I have posted the code

Comment: so, this is the only code which calculate the music duration and change the thumb based on the music playing. is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Set thumb offset for the thumb drawable. Example

```
android:thumbOffset="-3dp"
```

Also set appropriate left and right padding for your `SeekBar`. Example

```
android:paddingLeft="3dp" 
android:paddingRight="3dp"
```

Comment: yes.Seekbar was not in full width.and thumb was always 3 dp before the point.when it goes to end of seekbar thumb was before 3 dp of the points

Comment: try android:thumbOffset="8dp" for thumb drawable and set android:padding="0dp" for seek bar

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your seekbar style is wrong. You can set it like this:

```
<style name="MySeekBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">...</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">...</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">...</item>
    <item name="android:splitTrack">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">...</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">28dp</item>
</style>
```

Make sure `android:splitTrack` is `false`.